# Calendar style doesn`t affect DatePicker calender

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added the following style resource to customize the appearance of my DatePicker calendar. The Calendar is also affected but not the calendar of the DatePicker. See attached image.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.16"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.16"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.4"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[Calendar Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y3gR.png)

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the original default `Style` of the `DatePicker` you would see that the `Style` for the `Calendar` is explicitly assigned to the dedicated `DatePicker.CalendarStyle`. This makes sense as the intention is to restrict the `Style` to the `Calendar` of the `DatePicker`. It should not apply to the `Calendar` control in general.

So you must override the explicit default `Style`.
Given that your implicit `Style` is within the scope of the `DatePicker`, you simply have to set the `DatePicker.CalendarStyle` property to reference it:

```
<DatePicker CalendarStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type Calendar}}" />
```